# How to decrypt a JWT, in java, which is encrypted with JWE when the encrypted token is present in form of String?

Tags: java, encryption, jwt, jwe

I have a token in String format such as:

```
eyJhbGciOiJSU0EtT0FFUCIsImVuYyI6IkExMjhHQ00ifQ.K52jFwAQJH-DxMhtaq7sg5tMuot_mT5dm1DR_01wj6ZUQQhJFO02vPI44W5nDjC5C_v4pW1UiJa3cwb5y2Rd9kSvb0ZxAqGX9c4Z4zouRU57729ML3V05UArUhck9ZvssfkDW1VclingL8LfagRUs2z95UkwhiZyaKpmrgqpKX8azQFGNLBvEjXnxxoDFZIYwHOno290HOpig3aUsDxhsioweiXbeLXxLeRsivaLwUWRUZfHRC_HGAo8KSF4gQZmeJtRgai5mz6qgbVkg7jPQyZFtM5_ul0UKHE2y0AtWm8IzDE_rbAV14OCRZJ6n38X5urVFFE5sdphdGsNlA.gjI_RIFWZXJwaO9R.oaE5a-z0N1MW9FBkhKeKeFa5e7hxVXOuANZsNmBYYT8G_xlXkMD0nz4fIaGtuWd3t9Xp-kufvvfD-xOnAs2SBX_Y1kYGPto4mibBjIrXQEjDsKyKwndxzrutN9csmFwqWhx1sLHMpJkgsnfLTi9yWBPKH5Krx23IhoDGoSfqOquuhxn0y0WkuqH1R3z-fluUs6sxx9qx6NFVS1NRQ-LVn9sWT5yx8m9AQ_ng8MBWz2BfBTV0tjliV74ogNDikNXTAkD9rsWFV0IX4IpA.sOLijuVySaKI-FYUaBywpg
```

Now I want to decrypt this String through some java library and ultimately want to access the payload. Anyone done this so far ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably don't necessarily need a library:

```
String token = eyJ....;
String[] splitToken = JWTEncoded.split("\\.");

// splitToken[0] is the header, splitToken[1] is the payload and
// splitToken[2] is the signature
byte[] decodedBytes = Base64.decode(splitToken[1], Base64.URL_SAFE);

// You don't have to convert it to string but it really depends on what type
// data you expect
String payload = new String(decodedBytes, "UTF-8");
```

https://jwt.io has a nice little decrypter for you to test data

In regards to JWE the only library I could find is [this](https://connect2id.com/products/nimbus-jose-jwt) and an example to unencrypted JWE tokens can be found at the bottom of [this page](https://connect2id.com/products/nimbus-jose-jwt/examples/jose-jwt-parsing).
Note: I haven't tested this library so I won't be of much use beyond this, but it seems fairly straight forward.

Comment: Yes, but this is encrypted JWT with JWE and hence would have 5 parts like splitToken[0], [1], [2], [3], [4].

Comment: @HasebAnsari I've updated my answer for JWE. Good luck!

Answer (score 8):

The assertion you shared with us is a JWE serialized in [its compact representation](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7516#section-7.1). It has 5 parts separated by a dot (`.`) which are:

- Part 1: the header (`eyJhbGciOiJSU0EtT0FFUCIsImVuYyI6IkExMjhHQ00ifQ`)
- Part 2: the encrypted key - *depending on the algorithm, it may be an empty string* - (`K52jFwAQJH-DxMhtaq7sg5tMuot_mT5dm1DR_01wj6ZUQQhJFO02vPI44W5nDjC5C_v4pW1UiJa3cwb5y2Rd9kSvb0ZxAqGX9c4Z4zouRU57729ML3V05UArUhck9ZvssfkDW1VclingL8LfagRUs2z95UkwhiZyaKpmrgqpKX8azQFGNLBvEjXnxxoDFZIYwHOno290HOpig3aUsDxhsioweiXbeLXxLeRsivaLwUWRUZfHRC_HGAo8KSF4gQZmeJtRgai5mz6qgbVkg7jPQyZFtM5_ul0UKHE2y0AtWm8IzDE_rbAV14OCRZJ6n38X5urVFFE5sdphdGsNlA`)
- Part 3: the initialisation vector - IV *depending on the algorithm, it may be an empty string* - (`gjI_RIFWZXJwaO9R`)
- Part 4: the cyphertext (`oaE5a-z0N1MW9FBkhKeKeFa5e7hxVXOuANZsNmBYYT8G_xlXkMD0nz4fIaGtuWd3t9Xp-kufvvfD-xOnAs2SBX_Y1kYGPto4mibBjIrXQEjDsKyKwndxzrutN9csmFwqWhx1sLHMpJkgsnfLTi9yWBPKH5Krx23IhoDGoSfqOquuhxn0y0WkuqH1R3z-fluUs6sxx9qx6NFVS1NRQ-LVn9sWT5yx8m9AQ_ng8MBWz2BfBTV0tjliV74ogNDikNXTAkD9rsWFV0IX4IpA`)
- Part 5: the Additional Authentication Data - AAD - (`sOLijuVySaKI-FYUaBywpg`)

The header indicates at least the

- [`Key Encryption Algorithm` (`alg`)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7518#section-4.1) used to encrypt the content encryption key (CEK)
- [`Content Encryption Algorithm` (`enc`)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7518#section-5.1) used in conjunction with the CEK to encrypt the content.

In your case, The `alg` is `RSA-OAEP` and the `enc` is `A128GCM`.
According to these algorithm, you should have a RSA private key to decrypt the CEK and then use it to decrypt the cyphertext.

https://jwt.io mentioned in the accepted answer will not be useful as it does not support JWE, but JWS. The result shown with a JWE input will not give you the decrypted payload.
However, the https://connect2id.com/products/nimbus-jose-jwt resource will help you as it seems that the algorithms used for your token are supported.

Comment: Nicely explained.....I figured out this library of connect2id nimbus.....now the prob is I have 512 bits Key for A256GCM......us this possible in anyway.

Comment: To get the CEK, you have to decode it first (Base64UrlSafe => binary string) then decrypt it using the RSA-OAEP algorithm and the decoded IV.
Normally, with the A256GCM algorithm, the decrypted CEK should be a 256 bit string.

We can discuss [in private if needed](https://gitter.im/Spomky).

Comment: is it somehow possible to decrypt this String to JWT format ?